# How to prove $\gamma^0=(\gamma^0)^T$?

Tags: conventions, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

The Dirac gamma matrix $\gamma^0$ is symmetric in Dirac, Weyl and Majorana representation. Is it in general true that $\gamma^0=(\gamma^0)^T$? Can it be proved that $\gamma^0=(\gamma^0)^T$ in a representation-independent way?

Comment: How do you *define* $(\gamma^0)^T$ in a "representation-independent way" to begin with?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Why not? If $\gamma^0$ can be defined in a representation-independent way why not $(\gamma^0)^T$? Certainty $(\gamma^0)^2=I$ does not require any representation. Also, the property, $[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu]=2g^{\mu\nu}$ can be shown to hold in a representation independent way. Right?

Comment: You need the dual space to define the transpose in a coordinate independent way. Also look up Clifford algebras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot prove the property $(\gamma^0)^T = \gamma^0$ in a representation-independent way because it is not *defined* for the abstract [Clifford algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra) in which the objects we denote by $\gamma^i$ normally live. We shouldn't call them "matrices" in this case because they are not - the element of the Clifford algebra, as elements of an algebra, can be multiplied and summed with each other, but there is no natural notion of transpose on this algebra.

Algebras with a baked-in abstract notion that can correspond to the transpose (or to the complex transpose) are called [*-algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/*-algebra) or involutive algebras, but the standard Clifford algebra is not one of them (of course, you may pick some anti-homomorphic involution on the algebra, but there is no abstract reason to expect the standard representations respect this choice by sending it to the actual matrix transpose in the representations, so this is useless).

Comment: The last parenthesis is the key here.